# Linux training setup

Tags: linux, vnc

I want to give a tutorial/training type seminar on Linux. I also want to demonstrate certain Linux specific software with audience participation (on their own machines).

What is the best way to go about this? I have a Linux installation on my laptop with all the software, tools, etc that I want to demo. How do I easily create a bootable image (that I could run from a USB stick) from my existing install? (FYI: Live CD version does not have all the software [some of it is custom s/w] that I want to present)

Also, one other thing I thought of was having them VNC into my laptop while I'm presenting. Though I would have to test to see if it can handle 20 odd users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho, the best way is to create image for virtual machine and ask all participants to install virtual box/kvm/etc (it's better to use platform independent solution) on their machine before seminar.
In that case:

- you can do whatever you want with virtual machine without any influence on host machine.
- it works faster, than LiveCD (but only in case you have hardware virtualization support)
- participant can practice after seminar is finished
- there is no need in cdrom (a lot of modern laptops don't have it)

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom LiveCD/LiveDVD with the software you require, for e.g. Fedora the instructions are [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD). You can also put it on an USB stick.

I'm sure users knowledgeable in other distributions will chime in and add links to instructions tailored to their favorite.

Comment: They could also take the DVD home with them.